# Is the quickblox chat GUI or other modules GUI changeable?

Tags: quickblox

Just wanna ask is the GUI in the chat module or other quickblox modules changeable or it is fixed? Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's 100% changeable, feel free to update it as you need

All UI components are in code samples and they are open for any updates

Comment: Hi again Igor. Just wanna ask when the user register in the application, where the information will be stored? In a database at the client side like SQLite or at QB database?

Answer (score 0):

The information is stored on QB server. It is required for identification and allowing access to a particular functionality.